# Excel VBA UDF for concatenating is giving an Error message

Tags: vba, excel, udf

I'm trying to write a User Defined Function (UDF) in Excel that will take the values in a range of cells, and concatenate them in a certain way.  Specifically, I want to concatenate them in a way that the resulting string could be pasted into a SQL "in" function - i.e. if I have a range in Excel that contains:

```
apples
oranges
pears
```

I want the UDF to result in `'apples', 'oranges', 'pears'`

(i.e. no comma after the last value).

This is my code - it compiles OK in the VBA window, but when I use it in a worksheet I just get ERROR.  Any thoughts much appreciated - I'm a bit of a newbie at writing VBA.  And apologies for the vague question; I'm just at a loss to see which bit is causing the trouble.

```
Function ConcatenateforSQL(ConcatenateRange As Range) As Variant     



    Dim i As Long

    Dim strResult1 As String
    Dim strResult2 As String

    Dim Separator1 As String
    Dim Separator2 As String


    Separator1 = "'"  'hopefully the quotes act as escape characters
    Separator2 = "',"



    On Error GoTo ErrHandler



    For i = 1 To CriteriaRange.Count - 1                                              'all but the last one
              strResult1 = strResult1 & Separator1 & ConcatenateRange.Cells(i).Value & Separator2

    Next i


    'next, sort out the last example in the string

    For i = CriteriaRange.Count - 0 To CriteriaRange.Count + 0

      strResult2 = strResult1 & Separator1 & ConcatenateRange.Cells(i).Value & Separator1

    Next i


    ConcatenateforSQL = strResult2  

    Exit Function

ErrHandler:
    ConcatenateforSQL = CVErr(xlErrValue)
End Function
```

Comment: You have not defined `CriteriaRange`. Perhaps that should read 'ConcatenateRange'?

Comment: Also worth remembering that if you want to use it as a worksheet function from the workbook, it needs to be in a `Module` rather than in the `Worksheet` code object.

Comment: Ooh, good flag, SJR - I thought I'd changed all those but clearly not!

Comment: @Dave - it is in a module - maybe that just wasn't clear in the way I pasted it here?  Or am I potentially missing something?  It's Module1 in the VBA editor.

Comment: @s.turn No you're mot missing anything - you hadn't mentioned it was in a module so I figured it was worth mentioning..

Comment: @SJR - brilliant - I remembered the existence of Ctrl+H and it all works now!  Thanks very much.  It's good to know I was almost there, too.

Comment: @Dave - ah I see, I'll try and remember to specify that next time.

Answer (score 2):

I prefer the JOIN array approach.

```
Option Explicit

Function ConcatenateforSQL(ConcatenateRange As Range) As Variant
    On Error GoTo ErrHandler

    Dim r As Long, c As Long
    Dim vVAL As Variant, vVALS As Variant

    ReDim vVAL(1 To 1)
    vVALS = ConcatenateRange.Value2

    For r = LBound(vVALS, 1) To UBound(vVALS, 1)
        For c = LBound(vVALS, 2) To UBound(vVALS, 2)
            'Debug.Print vVALS(r, c)
            ReDim Preserve vVAL(1 To (r * c))
            vVAL(r * c) = vVALS(r, c)
        Next c
    Next r

    ConcatenateforSQL = Chr(39) & Join(vVAL, "','") & Chr(39)
    Exit Function

ErrHandler:
    ConcatenateforSQL = CVErr(xlErrValue)
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

This works for me (feel free to add in your error traps etc):

```
Function ConcatenateforSQL(ConcatenateRange As Range) As Variant
Dim csql As String
csql = ""
For Each cl In ConcatenateRange
    If Len(cl) > 0 Then
        If csql <> "" Then csql = csql & ","
        csql = csql & "'" & cl.Value & "'"
    End If
Next
ConcatenateforSQL = csql
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks, CLR - embarrassingly, the solution was just using Find & Replace to update the references I had accidentally left uncorrected!  However, I will study your version too, as it looks rather more elegant than mine.  Thanks again :-)

Comment: The `Join` approach is good, but means you can get blanks. My approach skips over blank cells. Another thing I have on my own installed add-in version (I use it every day for the same thing) is to skip over cells whose row height is zero (ie. hidden or filtered) which is a very handy feature too.

Answer (score 1):

A slightly different approach which allows you to specify the comma delimiter (it will be a comma if you don't specify). One could add a further argument for the other one.

```
Function ConcatenateforSQL(ConcatenateRange As Range, Optional sSep As String = ",") As Variant

Dim i As Long

Dim strResult As String

On Error GoTo ErrHandler

For i = 1 To ConcatenateRange.Count
    strResult = strResult & sSep & "'" & ConcatenateRange.Cells(i).Value & "'"
Next i

ConcatenateforSQL = Mid(strResult, Len(sSep) + 1)

Exit Function

ErrHandler:
ConcatenateforSQL = CVErr(xlErrValue)

End Function
```